# How do I pass in python script arguments to Azure CLI `az ml run submit-script` command?

Tags: python, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a python model training script that requires `argparse` arguments, but I have no idea how to pass them through Azure CLI command `az ml run submit-script`.

It seems like this is possible in the the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml(v1)/run?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml(v1)-run-submit-script

I tried:

```
az ml run submit-script -g resource-group -w workspacename -e experiment-name --ct compute_cluster --script_argument1 arg1 --script_argument2 arg2 train.py
```

and

```
az ml run submit-script -g resource-group -w workspacename -e experiment-name --ct compute_cluster <script_argument1> arg1 <script_argument2> arg2 train.py
```

but they both failed. I can't find working examples online, so I'm asking here.

EDIT:

I resolved the issue. You just have to put script arguments after `train.py` like below:

```
az ml run submit-script -g resource-group -w workspacename -e experiment-name --ct compute_cluster train.py --script_argument1 arg1 --script_argument2 arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [<USER_SCRIPT_AND_ARGUMENTS>] to do so, we are planning to add more common example in the guidance for user convenience.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add script arguments after train.py like below:

```html
az ml run submit-script -g resource-group -w workspacename -e experiment-name --ct compute_cluster train.py --script_argument1 arg1 --script_argument2 arg2
```